# Apache rewrite- Proxying adds extra index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to debug this for last two days and I'm at my wits end.

I'm trying to route the request to `http://localhost:xxx` when the query string have `escaped_fragment`. The rewrite rule is matched, and it is routed to proxy, but I'm not sure why the rewrite rule is restarted and an `index.php` is added to the request url.

Request URL:

`http://local.xxx.in/?_escaped_fragment`

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^woohoo.in
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.woohoo.in/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

# Only proxy the request to Phantomjs if it's a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://localhost:32768/$2 [NC,P,END,QSA,T=text/html]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L,R]


RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

RewriteLog for the request

```
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/ ->
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] RewriteCond: input='local.woohoo.in' pattern='^woohoo.in' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/ ->
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] applying pattern '^(?!.*?(\\.js|\\.css|\\.xml|\\.less|\\.png|\\.jpg|\\.jpeg|\\.gif|\\.pdf|\\.doc|\\.txt|\\.ico|\\.rss|\\.zip|\\.mp3|\\.rar|\\.exe|\\.wmv|\\.doc|\\.avi|\\.ppt|\\.mpg|\\.mpeg|\\.tif|\\.wav|\\.mov|\\.psd|\\.ai|\\.xls|\\.mp4|\\.m4a|\\.swf|\\.dat|\\.dmg|\\.iso|\\.flv|\\.m4v|\\.torrent|\\.ttf|\\.woff))(.*)' to uri ''
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] RewriteCond: input='curl/7.35.0' pattern='baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\\ link\\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator' [NC] => not-matched
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] RewriteCond: input='_escaped_fragment_=1' pattern='_escaped_fragment_' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] rewrite '' -> 'http://localhost:32768/'
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:32768/ -> http://localhost:32768/
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:32768/
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#18596f0/initial] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:32768/?_escaped_fragment_=1 [OK]
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/index.php -> index.php
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] applying pattern '^(?!.*?(\\.js|\\.css|\\.xml|\\.less|\\.png|\\.jpg|\\.jpeg|\\.gif|\\.pdf|\\.doc|\\.txt|\\.ico|\\.rss|\\.zip|\\.mp3|\\.rar|\\.exe|\\.wmv|\\.doc|\\.avi|\\.ppt|\\.mpg|\\.mpeg|\\.tif|\\.wav|\\.mov|\\.psd|\\.ai|\\.xls|\\.mp4|\\.m4a|\\.swf|\\.dat|\\.dmg|\\.iso|\\.flv|\\.m4v|\\.torrent|\\.ttf|\\.woff))(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] RewriteCond: input='curl/7.35.0' pattern='baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\\ link\\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator' [NC] => not-matched
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] RewriteCond: input='_escaped_fragment_=1' pattern='_escaped_fragment_' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'http://localhost:32768/index.php'
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:32768/index.php -> http://localhost:32768/index.php
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:32768/index.php
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 8971] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:57756] 127.0.0.1 - - [local.woohoo.in/sid#14b31a0][rid#1865e00/subreq] [perdir /home/robert/work/projects/gb/giftbigui/] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:32768/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=1 [OK]
```

-----------------EDIT----

My apache version is 2.4.12 and I found that this works fine in 2.2.x

Comment: I think mod_dir is looking for your DirectoryIndex'es one at a time via a subrequest. Maybe related to this bug that was supposed to be fixed in 2.4.9: PR53929.

Comment: It looks like that fix may have not been enough when you use the [P] flag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried DirectoryCheckHandler ON? It's needed to trigger the update in PR53929 unfortunately.  I don't recall exactly why this "fix" wasn't on by default -- maybe fear that 2.4.8 was too late to flip the behavior.

Comment: Checked as per your suggestions. Looks like it is working but now the content-type is set to 'httpd/unix-directory'. This causes the browser to download my file. How can I make it 'text/html'? Any suggestions

Comment: You could try T= in the rewriterule that does the proxying, as another kludge.

Comment: From code, H= might do it too -- with any dummy value. There is some inexplicable stuff in mod_dir that will be short-circuited

Comment: I tried T=, but no effect. I made it work in the code.

Comment: Did the code not issue a content type? Curious if still something needed bhere

Comment: I have committed a change that hopefully stops the 'httpd/unix-directory from leaking out of mod_dir in this scenario (rewrite in directory context, of something mapped to a dir, with no content-type on the response)